# How can I filter specific object value by the parameter of another object value

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6

This is the input. In the "posts" property, I have all of the posts. I need to filter the posts by "postIds" property.

```
   const users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Dan', postIds: [11, 22],posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]} ,
        { id: 2, name: 'Mike', postIds: [33], posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]},
        { id: 3, name: 'Lola', postIds: [44], posts: [
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]}
```

This is how the output should look alike:

```
   const users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Dan', postIds: [11, 22],posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
    ] ,
        { id: 2, name: 'Mike', postIds: [33], posts:[
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
    ]},
        { id: 3, name: 'Lola', postIds: [44], posts: [
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]}
```

I do believe that I have to work with "filter" and "some", but the option that I tried is not relevantly working:

```
const filterUserPosts = users.filter(obj=>obj.posts.id===obj.some(postIds))
```

What is the best option?

Answer (score 2):

The array you want to filter is `obj.posts`, not `updUsers` (which I assume is the same as `users`).

You need to loop over `users` to filter each of their `posts` properties.

You can use `includes()` to tell if the id of the post is in `postIds`.

```js
const users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Dan', postIds: [11, 22],posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]} ,
        { id: 2, name: 'Mike', postIds: [33], posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]},
        { id: 3, name: 'Lola', postIds: [44], posts: [
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]}];


users.forEach(u => u.posts = u.posts.filter(p => u.postIds.includes(p.id)));

console.log(users);
```

Comment: This mutates the original array, which is seen as bad practice. Try to do it with map/filter/reduce.

Comment: The question shows that this should replace the original `users` variable, so I took that to mean that in-place modification is OK.

Comment: Okay, I think that is valid :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the `postIds` array somewhere first, then call `.filter` on the `posts` array, filtering by whether the element being iterated over has an ID in the `postIds`:

```js
const users = [
        { id: 1, name: 'Dan', postIds: [11, 22],posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]} ,
        { id: 2, name: 'Mike', postIds: [33], posts:[
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },
    ]},
        { id: 3, name: 'Lola', postIds: [44], posts: [
        { id: 11, title: 'How to make it fast' },
        { id: 22, title: 'How to make it clearly' },
        { id: 33, title: 'How to can I do it' },
        { id: 44, title: 'How to he can do it' },]}
    ]
const output = users.map(
  user => ({
    ...user,
    posts: user.posts.filter(
      post => user.postIds.includes(post.id)
    )
  })
);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const usersWithFilteredPosts = users.map((user) => ({
  ...user,
  posts: user.posts.filter(({ id }) => user.postIds.includes(id)),
}));
```